# Not able to click Login Button (id=btnLogin)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am not able to click on the "Log in" button.

## Sharing below HTML

```
<div id="im">
    <input id="m_CultureCodeIptLogin" value="EN-US" type="hidden">
    <input id="m_AffIdIptLogin" value="714" type="hidden">
    <div class="ccerr"><p class="txt">The password you entered was invalid. Please try again.</p></div>

        <div class="field">


                <label class="errTxt">Password:<span class="red">*</span></label><span class="errtt" style="display:block"></span>
                <input id="m_Password" name="m_Password" maxlength="50" class="errField" autocomplete="off" type="password">

        </div>
        <p><a id="forgotPassword" class="hideDim">Forgot Your Password?</a></p>
        <p class="newEmail"><a id="editEmail2" class="hideDim" onclick="" href="javascript:ResetUpdateEmail()">New Email Address?</a></p>
        <div class="bctr">
            <button type="submit" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin" data-navelement="ipt cart|landing:log in"><span>Log in</span></button>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using below approaches (xpath, css, id), but it is not working.
I am not able to click the button.

Below is my test step control..

```
    <control tofind="#btnLogin" findby="cssselector" />
    <control tofind="#bctr" findby="cssselector" />
    <control tofind=".bctr" findby="cssselector" />
    <control tofind="#btnLogin" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="btnLogin" findby="id" />
    <control tofind="//*[@button='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//*[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//*[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//div[@class='bctr']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//button[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//*[@class='forgotPass']/div/button[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//button[contains(text(),'Log in')]" findby="xpath" />
    <action command="Click" />

Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object (Rest is exception...)
```

Let me know if you dont understand any part of my question.
Thank you

Comment: What code are you using? What all have you tried?

Comment: Hi Jeff i am using C#. for some reason my last part of post was missed. i have re-edited. now its showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <control tofind="#btnLogin" findby="cssselector" />
    <control tofind="#bctr" findby="cssselector" />
    <control tofind=".bctr" findby="cssselector" />
    <control tofind="#btnLogin" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="btnLogin" findby="id" />
    <control tofind="//*[@button='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//*[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//*[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//div[@class='bctr']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//button[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//*[@class='forgotPass']/div/button[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
    <control tofind="//button[contains(text(),'Log in')]" findby="xpath" />
    <action command="Click" />
```

A few lines of codes above have errors, I think.

```
<control tofind="#bctr" findby="cssselector" />, this line you were trying to locate an element using its id, but "bctr" is not a id. 
<control tofind=".bctr" findby="cssselector" />, this line you were trying to locate an element using its tag, but "bctr" is not a tag. 
<control tofind="#btnLogin" findby="xpath" />, "#" does not apply to xpath syntax, I think. it only applies to css selector.
<control tofind="btnLogin" findby="id" />, I am a bit confused here, why did you assign findby with 'id'?
<control tofind="//*[@button='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />, 'btnLogin' is not a value for 'button', button is its tag name, you should have written //*button[@id='btnLogin']
<control tofind="//*[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />
<control tofind="//*[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />, why did you use this line twice in a row?
<control tofind="//div[@class='bctr']" findby="xpath" />, this would probably work, but it depends on whether you would uniquely identify this button or not.
<control tofind="//button[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />, this would work, but it depends on whether you would uniquely identify this button or not as well.
<control tofind="//*[@class='forgotPass']/div/button[@id='btnLogin']" findby="xpath" />, this would not work, as 'forgotPass' does not have a match, I think what you meant is [starts-with(@class,'forgotPass')], which reads looking for an element that has a class attribute starts with "forgotPass".
<control tofind="//button[contains(text(),'Log in')]" findby="xpath" />, this would work, but you need to verify if this method is supported by your selenium driver.
```

Here is an useful link. 
http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf